# Ajax JQuery cross domain form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, cross-domain

I want to submit a form with Ajax jquery,

I want to send data from http://domain1.com to http://domain2.com

This is my form

```
    <form action="https://domain2.com/index.php/site/send_sms" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="with_slogan" value="yes" id="with_slogan" />


<input type="hidden" name="glist" id="glist" value="" />



Number: <br/>
<input type="text" name="to_mobile" value="" id="to_mobile" class="hide" />

<br/>


Message: (100 text) <br/>
<textarea cols="30" rows="6" maxlength="110" name="sms_body" id="sms_body"> --shaikatssj </textarea>



<br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sm-button-submit" /></form>
```

Ajax:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>﻿ ﻿ ﻿ 

<script>﻿ var url="https://domain2.com/index.php/site/send_sms";﻿ ﻿ var datastring = "with_slogan=yes&glist=&to_mobile=017147974&sms_body=teshejdsgjkjfdt&submit=submit";﻿ ﻿ $.ajax({﻿     url: url,﻿     data: datastring,﻿     type: "POST",﻿     crossDomain: true,﻿     success: function(e) {﻿         alert(e.responseText);﻿     },﻿     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { ﻿         alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); ﻿     }﻿ });﻿ ﻿ </script>
```

I tried ajax post but gained zero success.

Comment: *"gained zero access"* tells us next to nothing. Use your browser dev tools network and console to inspect the actual request. Also implement ajax error handler. You probably don't have CORS enabled on domain2 but more troubleshooting information is needed than what is provided. Also show your ajax code

Comment: I've updated ajax script,, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

- first in your form you dont need action and method post you are sending it via ajax script so delete it
- Add form id  form id='form'

Try using this script:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
 url: 'yourpage.php',
 data: $('#form').serialize(),
 success: function(){
        alert('success');
          },
});
 });
 }); 
});
```